# SlidingDrawer containing images

Tags: android

I require a sliding drawer in my application.
It should be placed at the bottom of the page.
It has to contain a set of images and I have to set a background colour for the sliding drawer. I saw some sample codes...But I am not getting a clear idea on how to do it. Can anyone plz help?

Comment: Which samples did you look at? Here's another one - https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Animation/. So your problem is how to assign the background color and/or image to the drawer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used HorizontalScrollView instead of SlidingDrawer.. I got it done now..